# Deflecting particles from a surface

Tags: particles, emission

I have a stream of spherical particles, being emitted from a cube face, going through a plane as shown in the crude image below. I'd like to have some of these particles be deflected by the plane at an angle back toward the cube (but not directly at it). I am not sure how to do that. Should I create a second particle system? And then, how can I get the particles to deflect when they hit the plane? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: to make the particles bounce on the surface, give the surface a  Physics > Collision. And maybe you need to create 2 particle systems to have both kind of particles, I don't know...

Comment: Thanks. When I do that both types of particles bounce off the surface. So I used a (probably) less efficient method by creating a hidden emitter in the surface that emits particles going in the opposite direction.